Why doesn't JPA Buddy "Create JPA Entities from DB" show tables?
I created a connection to my local database in IntelliJ and I managed to generate entities from database already once before. Now when I try it I get to that window but not a single table is shown.

I tried defining schema in database connection (even though it is default one - public) but that didn't change anything. This happened to me few months ago as well.

After the release 2024.1 the feature "JPA Entities from DB" is integrated with "Database" plugin. That mean that you see the same tables as on "Database" toolwindow. Are there any tables there?
The problem may be that this data is cashed. Try to click "Refresh" on the "Database" toolwindow or on the "JPA Entities from DB" dialog on the right from "DB Connection" field.

I have JPA Buddy plugin installed. I am not sure on which plugin do you exactly mean by "Database"? Maybe integrated functionality, because I can't find it among plugins? When I changed name of a table in database, that single table showed under entities creating window, so I guess that the problem is that those entities already exist. Maybe deleting them would fix it, but I managed to write annotations manually. Or maybe the problem is in caching, but refreshing connection didn't solve it.

If the entities already exist, they should be available under "Mapped Relations" node on the dialog.
